# Is sql views the proper solution

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table named 'Customers' which has all the information about users with different types (user, drivers, admins) and I cannot separate this table right now because it's working on production and this is not a proper time to do this.

so If I make 3 views: the first has users types only, the second has drivers and the third has admins.

My goal is to use 3 models instead one in the project I'm working on so
is this a good solution and what does it cost on performance?

Comment: Views seem like the right solution.

Comment: So you want to use Views to normalise the data? The fact that it isn't "under the hood" isn't changed by the views. What is the goal of these Views?

Comment: Also, you've tagged 2 very different RDBMS here, which are you actually using, SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Does it really matter which database system he uses.. Views,  partitons or another column in the where clause. Users normally don't see the statements , so lokk what you are familiar and confortable and use it. It won't really gives you more performance.

Comment: Personally, I've never been a big fan of views... they're easy, but they can get expensive (performance wise).   Given the option, I would explore Table-Valued Functions first. They are easy to consume and can be parameter driven as well.

Comment: *"Does it really matter which database system he uses."* yes, @nbk , especially if we start to suggest alternatives and/or provide (code) examples. The available functionality and syntax differences between SQL Server and MySQL can be very different.

Comment: For example, @JohnCappelletti, has suggested a TVF, however, I believe the MySQL has no such support for them (unless that has changed in recent history?).

Comment: I don't think MySQL has TVF,  I should have qualified SQL Server.

Comment: mysql uses procedures instead of TVF . But he has a huge table that could be divided into three new Tables, which he can't do at this time. so he hopes that 3 views make it something or other.

Comment: A Procedure isn't a replacement for a TVF, @nbk . They're very different objects, at least in SQL Server terms.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: The moment a view "gets expensive", a TVF will get even more expensive. Don't be afraid, forget your prejudices and try it.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Sorry, I don't agree.  Like anything, it's all about the context and implementation,

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Your suggestion was a general one.

Comment: Considering how different a query plan can be for a View and a TVF, I do agree with @JohnCappelletti here. Although the 2 objects *can* provide a similar result, they aren't designed to be. A TVF is supposed to be parametrised and if you aren't then (in my view) you're abusing the point of functions. On the other hand, a View is simply *"a virtual table whose contents are defined by a query"*. It's not parametrised, and effectively just a "pre-written" `SELECT` statement. Any Parametrisation is done *outside* the `VIEW` not inside; making their behaviour very different.

Comment: Which RDBMS?  The answer will differ!  MySQL dos not have "table-valued" anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How big is your table 'Customers'? According to the name it doesn't sounds like heavy one.
2. How often these views will be queried?
3. Do you have some indices or pk constraints on the attribute you're are going to use in `where` clause for the views?

> I cannot separate this table right now because it's working on
>   production and this is not a proper time to do this.

From what you said it sounds like a temporarily solution so it probably the good one. Later you сan replace the views with three tables and it will not affect the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that it is improper to give end-users logins directly into the database.  Instead, all requests should go through a database-access layer (API) that users must log into.  This layer can provide the filtering you require without (perhaps) any impact to the user.  The layer would, while constructing the needed `SELECT`, tack on, for example, `AND type = 'admin'` to achieve the goal.

For performance, you might also need to have `type` at the beginning of some of the `INDEXes`.